# Simple Modern OpenGL Hello World

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I want to make a simple modern OpenGL hello world Program. I already have some experience with modern OpenGL. I once even compiled my own shaders and all that. Now i want to use some more modern functions like glVertexAttribPointer. The Code Compiles but all i get is a black screen. No triangle is showing up. Is it some problem with my graphics card or am i doing something wrong?

I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dyue3MzJDss&index=5&list=PLRwVmtr-pp06qT6ckboaOhnm9FxmzHpbY

When i look in the comments many people say that all they get is a black screen.

```
#include <iostream>
#define GL3_PROTOTYPES 1
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <vector>
#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)NULL + (i))

GLuint vbo;
GLuint w=0;
float f[]={0.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0};    //vertex array

void init()
{
  glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glGenBuffers(1,&vbo); //generate an index for the vertexbuffer
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);    //use vbo as ARRAY_BUFFER
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(f),f,GL_STATIC_DRAW);//fill up the array with vertex and color-data
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(w);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
}


void display()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);       //draw it
}

int main()
{
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
  SDL_SetVideoMode(640,480,32,SDL_OPENGL);
  glewInit();
  Uint32 start;
  SDL_Event event;
  bool running=true;
  init(); 
  bool b=false;
  while(running)
  {
    start=SDL_GetTicks();
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                running=false;
                break;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                        running=false;
                        break;
                }
                break;

        }
    }
    display();
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    if(1000.0/30>SDL_GetTicks()-start)
        SDL_Delay(1000.0/30-(SDL_GetTicks()-start));
  }
  glDeleteBuffers(1,&vbo);
  SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: Looks as if you are drawing a black triangle on a black background. What happens when you change the background color?

Comment: Just for the records. This is not modern OpenGL. Modern (core profile) OpenGL requires you to use a Vertex Array Object and write your own Shaders. The code you have will use the fixed function pipeline.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't consider your code as "modern" OpenGL. It seems it uses the old *fixed-pipeline* with "steroids", something that OpenGL 2.0 allowed. Prefer a version starting with OpenGL 3.2. You will need: **a)** Setting a *Core Profile Context* by some SDL function and attach it to the window. **b)** Set that context as current (again, SDL). **c)** set `glewExperimental=GL_TRUE;` and then call `glewInit() **d)** Compile shaders, prepare buffers VBO and the VAO **e)** draw.

Comment: Hi Nothing changes when i change the background color besides the background color. And yes it is not truly modern opengl. I left some parts out because i think its simpler. It should still work. Before, i used functions like glDisableClientState and so on and it worked. Functions like glVertexAttribPointer are a bit more modern, it compiles but no triangle.

Comment: You can also make liberal use use of glGetError to see if you have caused an API error.